# Is there a way to open a list of URLs at once by simply copying and pasting that list in its entirety?

Tags: google-chrome

For example, a list with URLs separated by a comma or by a space.  Instead of having to copy and paste each URL into a new tab, it would be great to be able to launch all the webpages at once.  (In case it's helpful, I use Chrome as my browser.)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, this is on a Mac.

Comment: @music2myear, the idea here would be to launch a list of URLs in separate tabs in Chrome, without having to copy and paste each URL individually.  I'm not aware of any solutions, which is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a chrome extension for this - [**Copy All Urls**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk)

**Extension Description**:
Copy tabs URL to clipboard (formats : text, HTML, JSON or custom). Paste to open multiple URL at one go.

***WARNING***:
Each URL should ideally be in its own line - using comma or space usually won't work as intended.
However, it does have a feature called "**Intelligent paste**". I have not tested this feature.
Intelligent paste is supposed to "*Extract URLs from raw text when using paste feature (instead of processing pasted text line by line, with 1 line = 1 url). The only pitfall using this feature is that it doesn't get "special urls" like ones beginning with `file:///` or `chrome://`*".
Also, I use Chromium on a Windows 10 machine, but it should technically work in Chrome on a Mac.

**Tip 1**:
You can also enable keyboard shortcut for this extension inside Chrome: `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for **Copy** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for **Paste**.

**Tip 2**:
Enable `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` Flag - This will help you copy/paste from chrome tabs as well.

**Tip 3**:
This extension works well with another chrome extension: [LinkClump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj)
It lets you open, copy or bookmark multiple links at the same time.
I use the following options to open select multiple links in the extension -

- Opened as New Tabs: Activate by Right mouse button
- Copied to clipboard: copy `URLS & titles` - Activate by Right mouse button and <kbd>Shift</kbd> key
- Copied to clipboard: copy `URLS only` - Activate by Right mouse button and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key
- Copied to clipboard: copy `Titles only` - Activate by Right mouse button and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key